# How to Use Graph Learning Libraries to Predict Edges on a Graph where Each Node Has an Embedding?

Tags: supervised-learning, graphs, graph-neural-network, graphical-model, entity-linking

An undirectional graph $\mathcal{G}$ has the set of nodes $\mathcal{N}$ where each node has an associated unique embedding of $512$ dimensions. Note that the embeddings themselves are fixed, and not to be trained in this problem. So you can express the set of nodes as
$$\mathcal{N}=\{v\in\mathbb{R}^{512}\}$$ where $v$ denotes the embedding of any node.

Some of the node pairs are connected, i.e. we know there are edges. Some other pairs are *definitely* unconnected, i.e. we know there are *no* edges. The edges follow the transitive property, i.e. if $n_1, n_2\in\mathcal{N}$ are connected, $n_2, n_3\in\mathcal{N}$ are connected, we can assume $n_1, n_3\in\mathcal{N}$ are connected.

About the rest of the node pairs, we do not know.

###### The problem

Train a model based on the graph that, given any two nodes' embeddings, will predict whether there is an edge connecting them. Best if it gives a soft prediction, i.e. a probability of linkage instead of a binary yes/no.

###### Assumption

Edges are quite rare, i.e. sparse. So treated as a binary classification problem, probably accuracy is not a good metric.

###### Naive Approach

I can form a 1024 dimensional feature vector (concatenating the embeddings) for each node pair, then do a tabular supervised binary classification using the edge that I know are present.

However, this does not exploit the graphical nature of the problem, which is essential for some stakeholders. When I look on the internet, most problems seem to deal with training the embedding vectors rather than using fixed vectors.

###### What I am looking for

I do not need the entire code, but just a high level description of the sequential steps involved, best if in terms of relevant methods/objects from graph specific libraries in python such as networkx, scipy-csgraph, scikit-network, karateclub, neo4j etc. Any pointer to tutorials or documentations that deal with this problem using the above libraries will be sincerely appreciated too.